# Are anomaly sequences in Animatrix: Beyond and Thor 2: The Dark World both paying homage to something?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, thor-the-dark-world, the-animatrix

In both movie main characters enter an abandoned area where strange physical anomalies are occurring. After watching both sequences back-to-back, I noticed that there are some common ways in which the effects of anomaly are demonstrated, including:

- The protagonists are shown the place/anomaly by a group of kids who aren't supposed to be there.
- Anomaly is shown to reduce/nullify the effect of gravity on objects.
- Kids play with  bottle and the anomaly causes it to reset its physical state.
- Protagonist separates from the main group and finds a door that leads to some dark strange place.
- Rain is show to be localized in improbable ways (in Thor 2 it might have been Thor, not the anomaly).

Check the video for comparison:

Are those just very common tropes for haunted/strange locations or is there some common work of fiction from which this combination is taken, to which both movies are paying an homage?

Comment: It's always possible that *Thor 2*, er, "repurposed" the *Animatrix* scene, whether this was above board (and they actually paid for it) or not.

Comment: The rain was related to Thor think it's a thunder God thing

Comment: Koji Morimoto claims that the story in Beyond was an original creation; http://www.intothematrix.com/rl_cmp/rl_interview_morimoto.html

Comment: I think I was clear enough that I want to know not whether the story is original, but whether the elements used to tell it reference some other work. The stories of the two movies are totally different.

Comment: Just parallel/convergent thinking. I think I've seen this same type of localized anomaly scene in other tv shows too. Like, how different is this from the Simpsons Anomaly in the wall, which was taken from the twilight zone

Comment: I don't remember the specific episode. Did the anomaly in it contain any of the elements I described?